# What is something everyone uses but dont want to?

Tags: riddle

A thing everyone has to use eventually but really don't want to if that's an option. In fact no one wants to use this thing. It's never used used. It's always used brand new.

*hints It's neither a car nor  a contraceptive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a:

> Coffin

Because:

> Everyone dies eventually but most don't want to (though euthanasia and other burial methods [e.g. cremation] do go against the first sentence); you also don't use a coffin someone else has used.

Usually, this is clued as the following riddle:

> The person who makes it sells it
>  The person who buys it doesn't use it
>  The person who uses it doesn't know they're using it

Comment: Lol nice job. How did you know? I translated from chinese to english and this was my best attempt.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen Sounded familiar - see the other riddle I put up.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen Don't forget to accept this answer as correct (by clicking the checkmark on the left, beneath the answer's score and voting buttons). Welcome to Puzzling, btw :-)

Comment: I just asked my mom the same thing you posted under "following riddle" and her answer was "date rape drugs"